# Correct Ranking Loss Implementation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, loss-function, multilabel-classification

I have a multi-label problem and I am trying to implement the Ranking Loss as a custom loss in TensorFlow. (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.4894.pdf)

I made a simple CNN with a final Sigmoid layer of activations, to have independent distributions for each class.
The mathematical formulation splits the labels into two sets, positive and negative ones.

[image: rankloss]

My question is, what's the correct way of implementing it?

```py
def ranking_loss(y_true, y_pred):    
    pos = tf.where(tf.equal(y_true, 1), y_pred, tf.zeros_like(y_pred))
    neg = tf.where(tf.equal(y_true, 0), y_pred, tf.zeros_like(y_pred))

    loss = tf.maximum(1.0 - tf.math.reduce_sum(pos) + tf.math.reduce_sum(neg), 0.0)
    return tf.math.reduce_sum(loss)
```

The result is that for each sample, the activations scores from the positive and negative classes are summed independently.

```py
tr = [1, 0, 0, 1]
pr = [0, 0.6, 0.55, 0.9]
t =  tf.constant([tr])
p =  tf.constant([pr])

print(ranking_loss(t, p))

tf.Tensor([[0.  0.  0.  0.9]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32) #Pos
tf.Tensor([[0.   0.6  0.55 0.  ]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32) #Neg
tf.Tensor(1.2500001, shape=(), dtype=float32) #loss
```

The CNN has really poor precision, recall and F1 performances.
Switching instead to a standard Binary Cross-Entropy loss result in good performances, making me think that there's something wrong in my implementation.

Comment: That's an interesting question. I do not fully understand the formulation of the loss function - is c+ the number of positive labels for a given image i? If that is the case, what happens when none of the binary labels is positive? Also, would it be possible to clarify why the sums, e.g. `tf.math.reduce_sum(pos)`, were pushed into `tf.maximum`? A minimal example showing the desired loss value for a given pair (labels, predictions) would be really helpful. Thank you

Comment: @rvinas The paper states "The output of f(·) is a scoring function of the data point x, that produces a vector of activations. We assume there are n image training data and c tags." So, my understanding is that I should sum the scores of the activations for the positive labels and negative labels. If there are no positive labels the positive-sum term would be 0, giving a bad loss (1-0+(sum of activations of negative class)) to the model (I guess) as it should be! The simple example at the end seems to be numerically correct. What's your understanding of this loss?

Comment: I see how you got 1.25, but that's not exactly how I understood the formula. To make it easier, let's suppose that n=1. For the example that you provided, as I see it, you would have that both c+ and c- are 2. Then, the double sum would be expanded as: max(0, 1-0+0.6) + max(0, 1-0+0.55) + max(0, 1-0.9+0.6) + max(0, 1-0.9+0.55) = 4.5. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @rvinas Ahaa! Makes much more sense now, thank you! Using TensorFlow map_fn the calculation is extremely slow, so I used masks and reshape but seems still a bit slow! Do you know how I could improve it? https://gist.github.com/hichameyessou/039bdbfe0691076c9890c6a657a821c3

Comment: Cool :) I answered the question and provided an implementation that might be faster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the expansion of the sums is incorrect according to the formula and that the sums `tf.math.reduce_sum(pos)` and `tf.math.reduce_sum(neg)` cannot be pushed into `tf.maximum`. As I see it, the formula for your example would be expanded as:

max(0, 1-0+0.6) + max(0, 1-0+0.55) + max(0, 1-0.9+0.6) + max(0, 1-0.9+0.55) = 4.5

The second implementation that you provided in the comments section looks sensible to me and yields the result that I expected. However, let me provide an alternative:

```
def ranking_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_ = tf.cast(y_true, tf.float32)
    partial_losses = tf.maximum(0.0, 1 - y_pred[:, None, :] + y_pred[:, :, None])
    loss = partial_losses * y_true_[:, None, :] * (1 - y_true_[:, :, None])
    return tf.reduce_sum(loss)
```

This implementation is probably faster.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you! Little note, the maximum should have the same type of elements, ergo tf.maximum(0.0, 1 - y_pred[:, None, :] + y_pred[:, :, None])